# Hammer swipe event not working ios/chrome

Tags: javascript, angularjs, hammer.js

Ok well, I just implemented a scroller with hammer inside an angular directive, I need a div to be scrollable by page (some sort of carrousel) so I wen't with hammer.js everything works just great in desktop and android (any device) but I'm having issues with chrome on iOS and I'm not sure why is that happening, I can see hammer.js examples and they work on iPad as well so I'm sure I'm probably doing something wrong, so here is my html.

```
<div class="my-slidebox slidebox-container ng-isolate-scope" content-class="my-slidebox-content">
  <div class="slidebox" style="-webkit-user-select: none; -webkit-user-drag: none; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">
    <div ng-transclude="" class="slidebox-content" style="width: 2820px;">
    <!-- ngRepeat: product in vm.similarProducts --><div data-ng-repeat="product in vm.similarProducts" slidebox-items-ready="slidebox-items-ready" class="product ng-scope slidebox-item" style="width: 240px; margin: 20px;"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img data-ng-src="/spree/products/29/product/ror_ringer.jpeg?1404930806" src="/spree/products/29/product/ror_ringer.jpeg?1404930806"></a>
      <div class="caption text-left">
        <p class="brand-name ng-binding">Rails</p>
        <p class="product-name"><strong class="ng-binding">Ruby on Rails Ringer T-Shirt</strong></p>
        <p class="product-price ng-binding">$19.99</p>
      </div>
    </div><!-- end ngRepeat: product in vm.similarProducts --><div data-ng-repeat="product in vm.similarProducts" slidebox-items-ready="slidebox-items-ready" class="product ng-scope slidebox-item" style="width: 240px; margin: 20px;"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img data-ng-src="/spree/products/33/product/apache_baseball.png?1404930809" src="/spree/products/33/product/apache_baseball.png?1404930809"></a>
      <div class="caption text-left">
        <p class="brand-name ng-binding">Apache</p>
        <p class="product-name"><strong class="ng-binding">Apache Baseball Jersey</strong></p>
        <p class="product-price ng-binding">$19.99</p>
      </div>
    </div><!-- end ngRepeat: product in vm.similarProducts --><div data-ng-repeat="product in vm.similarProducts" slidebox-items-ready="slidebox-items-ready" class="product ng-scope slidebox-item" style="width: 240px; margin: 20px;"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img data-ng-src="/spree/products/41/product/spree_jersey.jpeg?1404930816" src="/spree/products/41/product/spree_jersey.jpeg?1404930816"></a>
      <div class="caption text-left">
        <p class="brand-name ng-binding">Spree</p>
        <p class="product-name"><strong class="ng-binding">Spree Baseball Jersey</strong></p>
        <p class="product-price ng-binding">$19.99</p>
      </div>
    </div><!-- end ngRepeat: product in vm.similarProducts -->
    <div class="right-fix ng-scope"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

this markup is for a horizontal list, so I have a container with a fixed width, then another container inside with a huge width so it'll be scrollable and then each individual element inside, I don't wan't the user to use the horizontal scrollbar, instead I wan't to show 'pages' of items every time the user swipes(mobile) or clicks a button(desktop), so then according to hammer documentation, the usage would be

```
var content = document.getElementsByClassName('slidebox')[0];
var hammer = Hammer(content, { touchAction: 'pan-y' });
hammer.on('swipeleft', function(){ alert('swipe left'); });
hammer.on('swiperight', function(){ alert('swipe right'); });
```

This just works great on both desktop and chrome/android, but not on iPad, I don't know if maybe the event is being captured by children elements or something, I've been dealing with this for a while with no luck, any help appreciated.